# im stuck at assert_template 'bookings/show' test in rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a simple project just to get a deeper understanding of rails and I'm stuck  at a simple test  `assert_template 'bookings/show'`  which lead to this error, i have been checking many times, can't find a clue  :

```
expecting <"bookings/show"> but rendering with <[]>
            test/integration/booking_submit_test.rb:17:
```

The related code is on below:

test/integration/booking_submit_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class BookingSubmitTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
     test "invalid booking submit information" do
        get booknow_path
        assert_no_difference 'Booking.count' do
          post bookings_path, booking: {date_of_tour: "2017-05-06", hotel_name: "xxx hotel", phone_number:123456 , number_of_pax:34 , pick_up_time: "9:00"} 
     end
     assert_template 'bookings/new'
    end

    test "valid booking submit information" do
        get booknow_path
        assert_difference 'Booking.count', 1 do
            post bookings_path, booking: {date_of_tour: "2017-05-06", hotel_name: "xxx hotel", phone_number:12345678901 , number_of_pax:34 , pick_up_time: "9:00"}
        end
        assert_template 'bookings/show'
    end
end
```

show.html.rb:

```
<% provide(:title, @booking.date_of_tour) %>
<div class="row">
 <aside class="col-md-4">
    <section class="user_info">
<h1>
<%= @booking.hotel_name %>
     </h1>
   </section>
  </aside>
</div>
```

new.html.rb:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Book the package now') %>
<h1>Book now</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@booking) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/errorbooking_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :date_of_tour %>
      <%= f.text_field :date_of_tour, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :hotel_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :hotel_name, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :phone_number %>
      <%= f.text_field :phone_number, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.label :number_of_pax %>
      <%= f.text_field :number_of_pax, class: 'form-control' %> 

      <%= f.label :pick_up_time %>
      <%= f.text_field :pick_up_time, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Book now", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

bookings_controller.rb:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
  end

  def create
    @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)    # Not the final implementation!
    if @booking.save
      flash[:success] = "You have submited the information successfully!"
      redirect_to @booking
    else
      render 'new'
    end

  def edit
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end
end


  private
  def booking_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:date_of_tour, :hotel_name, :phone_number, :number_of_pax, :pick_up_time )
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
get    'booknow'   => 'bookings#new'
  resources :bookings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the input is correct, the action executes a `redirect_to`, so the test you should use [`assert_redirected_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/ResponseAssertions.html#method-i-assert_redirected_to) :

```
test "valid booking submit information" do
    get booknow_path
    assert_difference 'Booking.count', 1 do
        post bookings_path, booking: {date_of_tour: "2017-05-06", hotel_name: "xxx hotel", phone_number:12345678901 , number_of_pax:34 , pick_up_time: "9:00"}
    end
    assert_redirected_to booking_path(assigns(:booking))
end
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering  this question  , i replaced that part with "assert_redirected_to bookings_path(assigns(:bookings))" but I'm still getting error  :Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/bookings> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/bookings/980190963>.
        Expected "http://www.example.com/bookings" to be === "http://www.example.com/bookings/980190963".
        Expected "http://www.example.com/bookings" to be === "http://www.example.com/bookings/980190963".

Comment: @Snailwalker I've updated my answer, I'd mistaken 'book' and 'booking' . Check again please.

Comment: Thank you very much .  it's working now. it's kind advance for me . :)